# jQuery Cycle plugin - Automatic height for containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle

I'm using the [cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) on some divs, like this:

```
<div class="sections">
  <div class="Section"> <img /> text </div>
  <div class="Section"> <img /> text </div>
  <div class="Section"> <img /> text </div>
</div>
```

all the .section divs have variable height, based on their contents.
How can I make cycle not to resize the container div (sections) to the largest child height? Instead I want the container to resize on every animation to the current child height.

Comment: What's your current CSS code?

Comment: there's no css at all for .sections/.section. Should I add any CSS?
the html above is located in the page sidebar. Below it other content can be added, that's why I need auto-height container

Answer (score 12, accepted):

set `containerResize` option to `0` and try. More option details [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html).

Comment: You have to use the full version, not lite.

Answer (score 21):

ok, I managed to do it by hooking a function on 'after' event:

```
function onAfter(curr, next, opts, fwd) {
  var $ht = $(this).height();

  //set the container's height to that of the current slide
  $(this).parent().animate({height: $ht});
}
```

found the info here:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-cycle-auto-height

Comment: This is great, but how can I get cycle to recalculate the height again after adding inline content dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

I've done it a little bit different:

```
  $('.cycle-list').cycle({
    containerResize: 0,
    before: function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag) {
      var container = $(this).parent();
      container.css('height', Math.max(container.height(), $(nextSlideElement).height()));
    },
    after: function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag) {
      $(this).parent().css('height', $(this).height());
    }
  });
```

My items had different height as well. In the before, it makes sure the container is big enough for the bigger of the 2 slides. In the after, it just resizes to the next slide.
This way it never over-flows because your container is too small.

note: this is for cycle 1